# Why spring cant see my package with style , font , jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, spring

Hi guys i have a question because[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHsAV.png) when i run my application spring cant see my style in  html and my page look like shit :

My code :

```
  <link href="../static/style/styleDistance.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="../static/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var NavY = $('.nav').offset().top;

        var stickyNav = function(){
            var ScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (ScrollY > NavY) {
                $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
            } else {
                $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
            }
        };

        stickyNav();

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            stickyNav();
        });
    });

</script>
```

But when i open in browser my page look like  :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6a4F.png)
I dont know why spring cant see my style can someone explain ?

my resource look that : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FYh6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="style/styleAdd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

i change like there and now it works

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some issue with the relative path for your CSS files `../`. Press `ctrl + u` in your page and click on the missing CSS, it will try to load your file, then check the browser url to see if you can figure it out what's going on.

Comment: i have one more question why js cant work when is in this same package templates like my html page ?